# ¿Cómo hacer imagen de un formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un formulario, el cual quiero convertir a imagen. Tengo el siguiente código pero solo me hace una imagen blanca o negra, pero no muestra la imagen del formulario.

este es mi código:

```
//esta instruccion manda la imagen del panel a otra clase para imprimirla
Image res = null;
res = CrearEtiqueta(pContainer);
return res;

//Esta crea la imagen del panel que hay en el formulario
public Bitmap CrearEtiqueta(Control control)
    {
        Graphics p = control.CreateGraphics();
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
        control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));
        return bmp;
    }
```

he intentado con otros códigos, pero no me funcionan, ya que me siguen dando el mismo resultado.

Comment: que es control? porque ahi esta el problema.. control deberia ser el form...

Comment: no, con el control me refiero al panel, que contiene los demas componentes

Comment: Probaste imprimir el form? el codigo es correcto (salvo por Graphics p qu eno hace nada)

Comment: no he probado con el form, por ahora solo tengo que me guarde la imagen generada en vez de imprimirla, solo he buscado códigos para ver si alguna variación de lo que tengo funciona pero aun nada

Comment: Espera. Que imagen generada? Como generas la imagen en el frame?

Comment: ese codigo que tengo es para generar la imagen de un panel de un windows forms, y despues la guardo en una ubicacion, y me deberia de dar la imagen con lo que hay dentro del panel, pero solo me hace una imagen totalmente blanca

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta [clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
 using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
 {
                    this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
                    bmp.Save("pruebadeImagen1");
 }
```

[ruta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTtwT.png)
[image: resultado]

Saludos

Comment: pero su codigo hace exactamente eso :/